# Using the suggested LyX sectioned nomenclature, why do deleted nomenclature entries still appear in the output?

Tags: sectioning, lyx, nomenclature

I'm using the suggested [LyX Nomenclature with Sections](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Nomenclature). When deleting a nomenclature entry, this stays somewhere hidden in the document and it is displayed in the output. Funny thing is that if trying to export to LaTeX (plain) the nomenclature entry does not appear in the LaTeX output. Any solution for this?

LaTex preamble:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Abbreviations}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{\item[\textbf{Mathematical Symbols}]}
{}
}% matches mathematical symbols
}% matches Subscripts
}% matches Abbreviations
}% matches Greek Symbols
}% matches Roman Symbols
```

LyX content:

Nomenclature (added from insert>list/TOC>Nomenclature)

Hello World. (insert here a nomenclature entry)

Comment: Sounds strange, does it still happen if you recompile, or if you close/delete the PDF and re-generate it? If yes, can you create a minimal example showing this? That is, remove all the content except a nomenclature entry or two from the document, and all irrelevant stuff from the preamble. It should still be able to reproduce the problem. Then upload the `.lyx` file somewhere, or open it in a text editor and copy the entire content of it into your question.

Comment: I have no clue on how to attach file to my question. But it's very simple, just copy the sectioned nomenclature to the preamble (and include ifthen package), add the nomenclature to the file and one single entry, compile, close the pdf, delete the entry and recompile. It really sounds strange, but it happens

Comment: You can't attach files, but what you can do is to open the `.lyx` file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad, Gedit, Kate, Textedit, etc.), copy everything, and add that text block to the question. Optionally do the same with the exported LaTeX source. I'll give it a try though, and check back later.

Comment: Hm, you're right. If I add two entries, and delete one, the output is correct, but if I add just one and delete that, it remains in the PDF. Perhaps LyX doesn't clear some temporary files or something, I really don't know. You could add a ticket in the [bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome) if you haven't already, it does sort of look like a bug.

Comment: @user41221 When you report the bug, can you link to it from here (so that anyone who finds this question can see whether the bug was fixed)?

Comment: The bug has been added to the tracker with [ticket #8095](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8905)

Comment: @user41221 thanks, nice bug report.

Comment: @user41221 the bug has been fixed [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/027b5dc4/lyxgit) (by Juergen Spitzmueller). It will be fixed in LyX 2.1 (starting with beta3, if there is one).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in LyX (http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8905) that will be fixed in the next version.